# Need advice to design my Azure Analysis Services Data model

Tags: powerbi, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

I am about to create an azure cloud business intelligence solution. Based on best practice, I will use Azure analysis services (AAS) to hold the data model and create Power BI reports who has live connection to AAS. This is the overall starting point. Then I have these challenges:

Challenge number 1: I want to be able to use the new features of Analysis Services as Calculation Group and Aggregation features. Right now I am using Visual Studio 2019 and SQL Server 2019 azure SQL database that contains a star data model. Can I create a data model in AAS that can take advantage of these new features and how can I do that? For example, can I use Visual Studio 2019 or do I need to create this in tools such as the Tabular Editor

Challenge number 2: If I have to make the model in the Tabular editor, how do I proceed and how do you integrate the model files into Azure Devops?

Challenge number 3: Is it possible to use the Power BI pro in the Power BI service to utilize these features?

All contributions and tips are received with thanks

Sincerely

Answer (score 1):

All this is changing rather rapidly, at present.

Currently Calculation Groups are previewed in SSAS 2019, and have not been rolled out in either Azure Analysis Services or Power BI.  Aggregations are available in preview in Power BI Premium, and aren't planned to ship in either SSAS 2019 or Azure Analysis Services.

Support for building Power BI Premium models in Visual Studio has also not shipped yet, as it's dependent on both XML/A endpoints and updated SSDT tooling.  Currently you would use Power BI Desktop to design models using Aggregations.  Later you can switch over ot using Visual Studio and SSDT when that tooling ships.

Comment: I am interessed by thé answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answers on my request. AS an following up question I have heard that it is possible to get power bi premium features using power bi embedded. If that is true I can that advantage of aggregations?

Comment: Power BI Embedded is very similar to Power BI Premium, except purchased through an Azure subscription, and targeted for applciation developers to embed content in custom applications. It has many, but not all, of the Premium features. And, of course, does not enable users to view reports in the Power BI online service